# Validation Limit 1 month (Angular 4+)

Tags: angular

I got problem in validation limit 1 month, i want have validation the Date can be limited to one month.

**This is my validation function**

```
public minmonthValidator() {
    let value = true;
    let endDate = this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['endDate'].value;
    if(endDate != null && endDate != undefined && endDate != ''){
      let monthnow = new Date();
      monthnow = new Date(monthnow.getFullYear(), monthnow.getMonth(), monthnow.getDay());

      endDate = this.dateconverter.DTPToDate(endDate);

      if(endDate >= monthnow){
        value = false
      }

    }
    return value;
  }
```

Note:
`DTPToDate` is only function from component dateconverter to remove the GMT format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the timestamp of next month using js Date.

//calculate next month

```
let monthnow = new Date();
monthnow.setHours(23, 59, 59);
monthnow.setMonth(monthnow.getMonth() + 1);


new Date(inputDate).getTime() > monthnow.getTime()
```

Comment: when i implement, my date must input next 1 month from date now, maybe i false explain questions about limit month. I mean 1 month limit is range from date now, example: date now is 16 oct 2018, when i input after 13 nov 2018 it will be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which date (now or enddate) you want to have 1 months limit. There are a few things you can do:

1. set endDate to the end of the day:

   endDate .setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
2. add 1 month to endDate:

   endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1)
3. compare endDate with monthnow using:

   endDate.getTime() < end.monthnow()